# Python, os.listdir() error

Tags: python, listdir

I'm writing this procedure

```
def get_special_paths(dir):
    detected_paths = []
    paths = os.listdir(dir)
    for path in paths:
        if path == r'__\w+__':
            detected_paths.append(path)
    for element in detected_paths:
        index = detected_path.index(element)
        detected_paths[index] = os.path.abspath(element)
    return detected_paths
```

and it raises a a type error as below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File"copyspecial.py", line 65, in <module>
    get_special_paths(dir)
  File"copysepcial.py", line 23, in get_special_paths
    paths = os.listdir(pathname)
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, builtin_function_or_method found
```

What's the meaning of that error and how do I fix it? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I suppose that what you pass as `dir` into the function is not a string. Actually there is a built-in function named exactly so, `dir`.

Comment: check if dir is a string also check converting dir to string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you passed the `dir` builtin function to the `get_special_paths`

```
>>> dir
<built-in function dir>

>>> os.listdir(dir)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, builtin_function_or_method found
```

Pass the path as string.

```
get_special_paths('/path/to/dir')
```

BTW, don't use `dir` as a variable name. It will shadow the above `dir` function.

Comment: you really don't need more than a minute!

Comment: Actually, I changed the name of passed value form dir to pathname but it's the same error!!

Comment: @user3305277, Did you pass it as string object? (not `dirname`, but `'dirname'` or `"dirname"`)

Comment: @user3305277, Could you update your question? (adding calling part of the code)

Comment: @user3305277, Please add the calling part in the question.

Comment: the call part is
get_special_paths('e:/')

Comment: What error occur? If there's error, I think it may not the same `TypeError` exception.

Comment: It worked, I was foolishly not passing a string in the call, thanks

Answer (score 0):

May be because `global_path` is not defined here:

```
for element in detected_paths:
    index = detected_path.index(element) # Here detected_path is undefined
```

make it `global_paths` and try:

```
for element in detected_paths:
    index = detected_paths.index(element)
```